# Why is this Bash variable empty?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm wondering why echoing $total in this Bash script doesn't show up as anything? In theory it should show up as the total of all the files in the folder, but it just returns blank.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l $1 |
while read file_parm
do
        size=`echo $file_parm | cut -f 5 -d " "`
        let "total += size"
        echo $size
done 
echo "The total size of the files in the directory <$1> is:"
echo $total
```

Comment: This is BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: ...also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs; parsing the output of `ls` is wildly unreliable. See the "getting metadata on a file" section for being able to efficiently and portably retrieve size (well, efficiently on systems with an intelligently-written `wc` command that knows how to use `seek()` and `tell()` or `fstat()`).

Comment: ...for an extra fun example, look at what happens to your `ls -l | cut -f 5` on Cygwin or like platforms, where usernames can contain spaces.